# GAE Datastore Put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
def post(self):
    update = self.request.get('update')

    if users.get_current_user():
        if update:
            personal = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Personal WHERE __key__ = :1", db.Key(update))

            personal.name = self.request.get('name')
            personal.gender = self.request.get('gender')
            personal.mobile_num = self.request.get('mobile_num')
            personal.birthdate = int(self.request.get('birthdate'))
            personal.birthplace = self.request.get('birthplace')
            personal.address = self.request.get('address')
            personal.geo_pos = self.request.get('geo_pos')
            personal.info = self.request.get('info')
            photo = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 0, 80)
            personal.photo = db.Blob(photo)
            personal.put()
            self.redirect('/admin/personal')
        else:
            personal= Personal()

            personal.name = self.request.get('name')
            personal.gender = self.request.get('gender')
            personal.mobile_num = self.request.get('mobile_num')
            personal.birthdate = int(self.request.get('birthdate'))
            personal.birthplace = self.request.get('birthplace')
            personal.address = self.request.get('address')
            personal.geo_pos = self.request.get('geo_pos')
            personal.info = self.request.get('info')
            photo = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 0, 80)
            personal.photo = db.Blob(photo)
            personal.put()
            self.redirect('/admin/personal')

    else:
        self.response.out.write('I\'m sorry, you don\'t have permission to add this LP Personal Data.')
```

Should this will update the existing record if the 'update' is querystring containing key datastore key. I try this but keep adding new record/entity. Please give me some sugesstion to correctly updating the record/entity.

Correction? :

```
def post(self):
    update = self.request.get('update')

    if users.get_current_user():
        if update:
            personal = Personal.get(db.Key(update))

            personal.name = self.request.get('name')
            personal.gender = self.request.get('gender')
            personal.mobile_num = self.request.get('mobile_num')
            personal.birthdate = int(self.request.get('birthdate'))
            personal.birthplace = self.request.get('birthplace')
            personal.address = self.request.get('address')
            personal.geo_pos = self.request.get('geo_pos')
            personal.info = self.request.get('info')
            photo = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 0, 80)
            personal.photo = db.Blob(photo)
            personal.put()
            self.redirect('/admin/personal')
        else:
            personal= Personal()

            personal.name = self.request.get('name')
            personal.gender = self.request.get('gender')
            personal.mobile_num = self.request.get('mobile_num')
            personal.birthdate = int(self.request.get('birthdate'))
            personal.birthplace = self.request.get('birthplace')
            personal.address = self.request.get('address')
            personal.geo_pos = self.request.get('geo_pos')
            personal.info = self.request.get('info')
            photo = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 0, 80)
            personal.photo = db.Blob(photo)
            personal.put()
            self.redirect('/admin/personal')

    else:
        self.response.out.write('I\'m sorry, you don\'t have permission to add this LP Personal Data.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do a query when you know the key: Simply call db.get() on the key to retrieve it directly, which is much faster than doing a query.

As to why you're creating a new record each time, it looks like you're not passing in 'update' to your page correctly. Try logging the query string parameters to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Is db.get() above correct? how to log the query within the Local SDK?
Thx Nick

Comment: Yes, the code you've used above should work, presuming 'update' is a string key - _not_ a key name. Use the logging module (eg, logging.warn) to log, and look at the console window to see logged messages.

Comment: BadKeyError: Invalid string key Raises, i get the 'update' string from a query string e.g. /personal?update=ahJsaXZlbGlob29kcHJvZHVjZXJyDwsSCFBlcnNvbmFsGM0wDA. How to assign this to be correct string key? Thx for your help Nick. I'm just verymuch newbie .... :-)

Comment: That does look like a string key (not a key name). You simply need to make sure it really is one, and that it's not being mangled/truncated/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I finally answer this myself, Thanks for Nick Johnson guide on this.
I cannot get the query string url as 'string key' that always raise BadKeyError: Invalid string key exception.

I try to put this 'update' string as hidden field on html edit form and this works since 'update' is a valid 'string key' now.

```
def post(self):
    update = self.request.get('update')

    if users.get_current_user():
        if update != '':
            personal = Personal.get(db.Key(update))
```